# ruby - passing qr codes details from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm new to `ROR`. I would like to generate three qr code and transfer it controller to view.

but i'm facing the following error
`undefined method each' for #<RQRCode::QRCode:0x007fded6a37368>`

my controller is:

```
while no_of_device.to_i > 0 do
            device_id = device.to_s+model_no.to_s
            @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(device_id)
            no_of_device = no_of_device.to_i - 1
            model_no = model_no.to_i + 1
            arr.push(@qr)
        end
```

my view is:

```
<% @qr.each do |qr| %>
    <%= qr.as_html %>
<% end %>
```

what i'm doing is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are push to the `arr` in the controller. You have to make it instance variable (by adding `@`) to access it from the view file.

```
@arr = []           
while no_of_device.to_i > 0 do
                device_id = device.to_s+model_no.to_s
                @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(device_id)
                no_of_device = no_of_device.to_i - 1
                model_no = model_no.to_i + 1
                @arr.push(@qr)
            end
```

In the view you have to iterate through the array.

View:

```
<% @arr.each do |qr| %>
    <%= qr.as_html %>
<% end %>
```

You were getting this error because you were trying to iterate an active record object(`@qr`).